# Problem Installing Groovy on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to begin working with ROS and I am completely new to ROS and I already have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed on my desktop. I configured the repositories, set up the sources.list, set up the keys ran `sudo apt-get update` and then called `sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-desktop-full` but I am getting the following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  ros-groovy-desktop-full: Depends: ros-groovy-ros-tutorials (= 0.3.9-0precise-20130125-2301-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-nodelet-core (= 1.7.14-0precise-20130129-0936-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-navigation-tutorials (= 0.1.1-s1360129594~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-geometry-tutorials (= 0.1.3-s1359158777~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-orocos-kinematics-dynamics (= 0.2.3-s1359529309~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-filters (= 1.6.0-s1359446119~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-slam-gmapping (= 1.2.7-s1360121475~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-ros (= 1.9.42-0precise-20130125-2011-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-qt-gui-core (= 0.2.12-0precise-20130129-0828-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-python-qt-binding (= 0.2.8-0precise-20130125-2005-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-vision-opencv (= 1.10.4-0precise-20130202-1411-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-perception-pcl (= 1.0.28-0precise-20130205-2103-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-rqt-common-plugins (= 0.2.10-0precise-20130202-1459-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-actionlib (= 1.9.11-0precise-20130125-2100-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-pluginlib (= 1.9.18-0precise-20130129-0745-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-image-pipeline (= 1.10.4-0precise-20130205-2106-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-bfl (= 0.1.0-s1359146203~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-stage (= 1.6.7-s1359158824~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-rqt-robot-plugins (= 0.2.8-0precise-20130205-1931-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-image-common (= 1.10.0-0precise-20130129-0904-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-bond-core (= 1.7.10-0precise-20130125-2050-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-common-tutorials (= 0.2.3-s1359455939~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-ros-comm (= 1.9.41-0precise-20130125-2334-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-physics-ode (= 1.8.0-s1359145319~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-driver-common (= 1.6.5-0precise-20130126-0009-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-executive-smach (= 1.2.0-s1359158282~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-common-msgs (= 1.9.14-0precise-20130125-0519-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-dynamic-reconfigure (= 1.5.31-0precise-20130125-2328-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-image-transport-plugins (= 1.8.18-0precise-20130208-0327-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-xacro (= 1.6.1-s1359159008~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-robot-model (= 1.9.32-0precise-20130126-0005-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-bullet (= 2.80-s1359145269~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-visualization-tutorials (= 0.7.4-s1360309036~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-geometry (= 1.9.29-0precise-20130125-2326-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-documentation (= 1.5.3-s1359159538~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-laser-pipeline (= 1.5.5-s1360106441~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-simulator-gazebo (= 1.7.11-s1360100419~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-geometry-experimental (= 0.2.4-s1359531871~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-robot-model-tutorials (= 0.1.2-s1359145325~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-rviz (= 1.9.20-0precise-20130205-1908-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-diagnostics (= 1.7.9-0precise-20130129-0818-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-navigation (= 1.10.1-s1360111325~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-robot-model-visualization (= 0.1.2-s1359158420~precise) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56263/problem-installing-groovy-on-ubuntu-12.04-lts/) by [nicobari](https://answers.ros.org/users/4293/nicobari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2013-02-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on 2013-02-25**:
Do you have enabled the community packages? The easiest way is to run `sudo synaptic`, go to Settings|Repositories and activate all Ubuntu sources except Source Code, i.e. main, restricted, universe and multiverse.

**Comment by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on 2013-02-28**:
Are all your system packages up-to-date? Run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and make sure that no packages have to be upgraded. Do you have any other third party repositories or PPAs which might clash with the ROS ones? Lastly, try to install the bare-bones system `ros-groovy-ros` and see if that works

**Comment by [ferre](https://answers.ros.org/users/4789/ferre/) on 2013-04-29**:
has someone found a solution to this issue? I am not able to find a solution :-/ This thread doesn't seem to fix it either http://bit.ly/12W9dLy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check if you have been selected right distro on source.list.
This happened to me, that I put the ubuntu 12.10 instead of 12.04, and this occurred to me :)

---

Originally posted by [Miško](https://answers.ros.org/users/9746/mi%C5%A1ko/) with karma: 31 on 2014-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0